# Как делать автоматическое получение контента по внешнему ключу

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

есть таблица ads. В ней около 80 полей. Мне нужно получить все значения этих полей. Но некоторые поля связанны по внешнему ключу с другими таблицами. Как я могу сделать чтобы в запросе место значения поля я сразу получал контент.
Объясню на примере:
Вот пример одного из полей
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
оно по внешнему ключу связана с таблицей employ_type
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
таблица employ_type:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При запросе "SELECT * FROM `ads`" он мне выдает idшник строки из таблицы employ_type
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Какой запрос должен быть чтобы он выводил не просто idшник значение, а поле content.
Да, я понимаю как сделать это для одного поля, но мне надо сделать это для множества полей, без ручного прописывания для каждого.
Таблицы к которым идут внешние ключи имеют одинаковую структуру, отличаются только названия полей и таблиц.
Таблицы на Mysql.

Comment: Автоматически - никак, ибо операция затратная и не всегда необходимая. Вручную - в запросе через `JOIN`. Можно сделать представление (view) для того чтобы не писать длинный запрос каждый раз

Comment: *без ручного прописывания для каждого* Вот это вряд ли...